# A linear transformation $t$ is one-one if and only if $Ker(t) = {0}$. Why?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

A theorem in my textbook states:

**A linear transformation $t$ is one-one if and only if $\  \mathbf{Ker}(t) =$ {$0$}**.

I understand the *only if*  bit, that is, one-one implies $\ \mathbf{Ker}(t) =$ {$0$}. $ \ $  But how does $\ \mathbf{Ker}(t) =$ {$0$} $ \ $ implies one-one?  $t$ might map only the $0$ vector to the $0$ vector of its imageset, but what if it maps some other vector**s** to *one* single vector in its imageset?  Then it's surely not one-one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: If $u$ and $v$ are vectors with the same image, what can you say about the image of $u-v$?

Comment: Okay, I get it.  t(u)=t(v), so t(u)-t(v)=0, so t(u-v)=0 so u-v $\in$ ker(t).  But since ker(t)=0,  u-v must equal 0, hence u=v!  so t is one-one!

Comment: Can you please confirm if I'm right? Thanks.

Comment: Yes! Exactly! This happens because the transformation $t$ is linear, hence  $t(u-v)=t(u)-t(v)$.

Comment: I find it to be a rather unintuitive result : ) But it makes sense now.  Merci!

Comment: @Élodie For a function to be 1-1, every distinct input must result in a distinct output, but if the kernel is nontrivial, there’s an entire vector space worth of inputs that all get mapped to zero. Hardly distinct.